# Ambiguous call operator overload weirdly resolved by introducing unrelated call operator - clang vs gcc

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overloading, language-lawyer

Consider the task of implementing an `overload_two` class so that the following code compiles:

```
int main()
{
    overload_two o{
        [](int) { return 1; },
        [](char){ return 2; }
    };

    static_assert(o(0) + o('a') == 3);
}
```

A first attempt would look something like this:

```
template <typename F, typename G>
struct overload_two : F, G
{
    overload_two(F f, G g) : F{f}, G{g} { }
};
```

Of course, this fails with the following error (gcc 11.0.1):

> ```
> <source>:15:22: error: request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous
>    15 |     static_assert(o(0) + o('a') == 3);
>       |                      ^
>
> <source>:12:9: note: candidates are: 'main()::<lambda(char)>'
>    12 |         [](char){ return 2; }
>       |         ^
>
> <source>:11:9: note:                 'main()::<lambda(int)>'
>    11 |         [](int) { return 1; },
>       |         ^
> ```

The intended solution is to bring both `F::operator()` and `G::operator()` into scope with `using` declarations. However -- very surprisingly -- introducing a seemingly unrelated `operator()` also works:

```
template <typename F, typename G>
struct overload_two : F, G
{
    overload_two(F f, G g) : F{f}, G{g} { }
    auto operator()(F&) { }  // wtf?
};
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jP6MjKq4j)

---

What's more, clang 13.0.0 seems to work without neither the `using` declaration or the random `operator()`: [**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TvjG76sb1).

---

My questions are:

1. Is gcc correct in rejecting the implementation of `overload_two` without any `operator()` or `using` declaration?
2. Is gcc correct in accepting the implementation of `overload_two` with `operator()(F&)` and no `using` declaration?
3. Is clang correct in accepting the implementation of `overload_two` without any `operator()` or `using` declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes. Name lookup for the name `operator()` is ambiguous because it found the name in both bases (see [[class.member.lookup]/5.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#5.2)). That's an error right there, don't pass GO, don't collect $200.
2. Yes. The unrelated `operator()` makes name lookup succeed by hiding the base class members. Because your lambdas are captureless, they are implicitly convertible to function pointers, and these implicit conversions are inherited by the derived class. When your class is convertible to function pointers (or references), overload resolution will additionally generate [surrogate call functions](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.call.object#2) from these conversions. Those will be selected for the calls in the example.
3. No. See #1.